# UWP: binding to view model property

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

In my view model:

```
public string MyProperty{ get; set; }

public MyViewModel()
{
     MyProperty = "hello";
}
```

I have defined a string property.

Now, from my page, I want to bind to this property:

```
Text="{Binding MyProperty}"
```

but this is not working - no text is being show.  What am I missing?

*Edit:*
My view model inherits from:

```
public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

*Edit 2:*

I have modified my view model:

```
private string _myProperty;

        public string MyProperty
        {
            get => _myProperty;
            set => Set(ref _myProperty, value);
        }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            _myProperty = "hello";
        }
```

and the xaml:

```
Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

but it's still not working.

*Edit 3:* I think the problem is that the `Text` property is a registered dependency property of a custom control:

```
public sealed partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(s_textProperty);
            set => SetValue(s_textProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty s_textProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

and in the control's xaml I have:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
```

This:

```
<MyControl Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
```

is in the page where I use the custom control.

Comment: Did you set the datacontext on the view?

var view = new MyView();
var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
view.DataContext = viewModel;

Comment: @JanWidmer I have.

Comment: Do you want to bind the text of a label?

Comment: Put a debug point in the getter and setter of the property?

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, yes, related to the custom control (edited my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and haveproperty accessors like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private string _myProperty;

public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In XAML:

```
Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Remarks:

Mode = TwoWay - property will change both on UI and in code if changed by either one.
UpdateSourceTrigger - Reacts on the PropertyChanged event.
Also, read about DataContext :)

Comment: Id recommend a class BaseViewModel with [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface] and every ViewModel implements this

Comment: I actually inherit from `Observable`. I've edited my question.

Comment: @Eutherpy, you are still missing getter and setter methods. See the body of my "MyProperty" :)

Comment: @JanWidmer, yep, I would go this way as well :) but that would be a lot of code that has very less to do with the original question :)

Comment: @Eutherpy, also, one thing I remember now - if you have correctly instrumented NotifyPropertyChanged (in setter mainly), after you change the value and the setter is hit, immediatelly after that the getter should be hit as well (due to getting actual value for UI)

Answer (score 3):

I recomment adding the PropertyChanged.Fody Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/)

Its simple to implement it.

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyProperty = "hello";
    }
}
```

As @DavidHruška said, edit the binding in XAML too.

Answer (score 2):

Your setter needs to explicitly call the Observable.Set() Method:

```
private string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{ 
   get {  return _myProperty; }
   set { this.Set<string>(ref _myProperty, value); }
}
```

Unfortunately, autos don't implement INPC for you, so you can't use them. Microsoft had this as a [feature request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2255378-inotifypropertychanged), but it appears to be getting turned down.